# Apache2: rewrite query string

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following url:

http://www.mysite.com/blog.php

and I want it to rewrite to:

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?goto=blog

How to do this in Apache2?

I've seen many examples of doing it the other way around...

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite all .php to index, you should do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ index.php?goto=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if you would like to rewrite only some files:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog.php|other_file.php)/(.*)?$ index.php?goto=$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the really useful response. I found some answers at: http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/rewrite-rules-practical-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
^/(.*)\.php$ /index.php?goto=$1
```

This should work even with other pages, not only with the blog.php.
Have a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html).